# Dependencies in {ASSEMBLY NAME}.deps.json file in publish ASP.NET Core output

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, dependencies, publish

When publish an ASP.NET Core project by framework-dependent, I get an `{ASSEMBLY NAME}.deps.json` file which contains project's dependencies.
Are all of dependencies in `.dep.json` file used in the project? It seems that have more dependencies than are used dependencies?

Comment: Then description in this [Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/) is `If the app uses a NuGet package that has platform-specific implementations, all platforms' dependencies are copied to the publish folder along with the app.`

Comment: Yes, I know. But if I wanna say an example, my application is mvc and I don't use razor pages, but "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor" dependency is added to {ASSEMBLY NAME}.deps.json file. How can I remove extra dependencies like this from this file?

Comment: I don't think you can remove it.